# Filter this json array by date range create new json array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a json array with these keys/values

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "date": "2013-15-5",
            "position": "23",
            "race" : "2"
        },
        {
            "date": "2013-15-6",
            "position": "15",
            "race" : "4"
        },
        {
            "date": "2013-15-7",
            "position": "20",
            "race" : "5"
        },
        {
            "date": "2013-15-8",
            "position": "9",
            "race" : "9"
        }
    ]
}
```

Given I have two variables storing a `$from`  and `$to` date in the same format `2013-15-5`

How can I filter this json array so the output shows the range for *2013-15-6* - *2013-15-8* thanks

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "date": "2013-15-6",
            "position": "15",
            "race" : "4"
        },
        {
            "date": "2013-15-7",
            "position": "20",
            "race" : "5"
        },
        {
            "date": "2013-15-8",
            "position": "9",
            "race" : "9"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: is the array always sorted by date as in your example?

Comment: @koala_dev yes it is always sorted by date

Comment: To filter for a date range you have to convert the date string into internal date values.

Comment: `json_decode`, `array_filter`, anonymous functions, `DateTime`. :)

Comment: You filter that by writing the code for it. Where do you hit the roadblock to sketch up some code?

Answer (score 2):

well convert the json to a php array, and pass it through `array_filter` as below

```
array_filter($array, function ($item) {
       $from = strtotime("2013-15-6");
       $to = strtotime("2013-15-8");

       $ts = strtotime($item['date']);
       if ($ts >= $from && $ts <= $to) return true;
       return false; 
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for trying to help. I was getting an error because of the anonymous function while testing and tried to move the function $item outside the filter but not very good with this. Can you take a look at what i've done and maybe help make the changes needed please http://codepad.org/2s9uh8tD thanks

Comment: @Anagio you didn't name the variable properly. http://codepad.org/kTuMFtvt

Comment: Thanks but the second print_r still shows all 3 dates and doesn't seem filtered?

Comment: http://codepad.org/9WXpGXn7 updated but you need to update your date it has Y-d-m which is not a supported format @Anagio